# How to get sikuli-script.jar for Windows 64 bit machine

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script

I have downloaded sikuli-setup.jar and successfully able to install it. I am able to run sikuli from GUI but I want to run sikuli script from eclipse which require sikuli-script.jar.
Please let me know the location or way to download it.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of sikuli-script.jar you can use sikuli-java.jar as follows:

1. Download last setup from [here](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.0.1/+download/sikuli-setup.jar) and put it in in a dedicated folder (e.g d:\sikuli)
2. Run the downloaded jar file sikuli-setup.jar (a. Simply double click on sikuli-setup.jar or b. from command prompt execute the command: java -jar sikuli-setup.jar)
3. Choose options as shown
   [image: setup options]
4. Confirm download

   [image: download jar file]
5. Include sikuli-java.jar in your project build path (let eclipse just link to its location)
6. Usage sample [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html)

Hopefully it would work & ENJOY...

Comment: Thanks for this nice and helpful post with screen shots. I am RaiMan the current developer of SikuliX, which you are referencing above. One comment though: option 6 is only recommended if you want to produce a package that contains ALL native libs for ALL supported system (useable e.g. on a network drive in a team network). If you plan to use SikuliX only on the system you are running setup, this option is not needed. The packages out of the box support 32-Bit and 64-Bit Java.

Comment: NOTICE: for Windows YOU MUST BE ADMINISTRATOR. Otherwise the setup fails in a cryptic way: the runSetup tells you to runSetup again, and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can dowmload it from

> https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download
>   download Slikuli-setup.jar . It is used for both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs.

Comment: I am RaiMan, current developer of SikuliX. It is always important to be aware of the fact, that it is not the bitness of the machine/system, you are running on, but that of the used Java. It is a speciality of Windows 64-Bit systems, that you can have both: Java 32-Bit and Java 64-Bit at the same time (which in turn can lead to odd situations).