# How to generate 64-bit version of sikuli JAR?

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I am working on developing test automation code in selenium, I want to use 'sikuli' inside my code to handle windows and Flash objects in my web application, 
I'm using 64-bit JVM, but there is no 64-bit version of Sikuli available, this is resulting in an error while running the code,

*"Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"*

I could not find a 64-bit sikuli Jar on internet, but I found that Sikuli source code is hosted on GitHub, could someone help me understand if I can use that source code and compile it into a jar of 64 bit version?
I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: please check the link below hope it helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114511/how-to-get-sikuli-script-jar-for-windows-64-bit-machine

Answer (score 0):

If you install Sikuli 1.0.1 you have the option to install 6 packages with it as well. I would recommend installing the first 5. Then you will have all the things you are ever going to use.

If you also work on different sytems other then Windows, the 6th packages is also advisable.

I have installed all 6.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working, here is what I did,

- Download the sikuli set-up Jar from
  "https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.0.1/+download/sikuli-setup.jar"
- Save this jar in a folder 'SikuliSetup',now create a sub directory
  'Downloads' which will come into picture later.
- Run the above Jar,    this will generate two files under the above
  directory.
- Now run the 'runSetup.bat' file generated from above    setup. This
  will start the    setup, now select the 4th and 6th    option in the
  'sikulisetup' pop-up  and click on 'setup Now'.
- The above step will fail for most people  due to default security
  issues.
- If the above step fails then you need    to download an offline
  version of this jar from this URL
  "https://launchpadlibrarian.net/156273987/Sukuli-1.0.1-Offline-Setup-Java-option3-option4.zip".
- UnZip the above file and copy the '1.0.1-3.jar' file to 'Downloads'
  directory created under the 'SikuliSetup' directory previously.
- Now run the    'runSetup.bat' file again, this will generate a new
  jar file    'sikuli-java' and its dependent libraries under 'lib'
  folder.
- That's it, now copy this jar 'sikuli-java.jar' to your java build
  path in eclipse.
- Now Java will use this sikuli libraries without any issues.
- Once after you setup the jar file under build path, restart the
  system    and login again.