# sikuli+selenium+java : need to understand how sikuli works

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am new to sikuli.I need to understand how it works.
I install sikuli and played little bit with IDE.

However,I need to understand how can I make use of sikuli using java + selenium.
In our application, we have high charts that we need to automate.We are thinking of using sikuli for same.We want to compare image that we have saved as an expected with the image that is seen on UI.
I read some blogs and at many places they have mentioned to use jar sikuli-script.jar.I didn't find this jar on sikuli site.

Any pointers as how to integrate sikuli with java+selenium will be helpful to me.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114511/how-to-get-sikuli-script-jar-for-windows-64-bit-machine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to Sikuli API, you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
      <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Just get that into your maven pom together with whatever Selenium version you're using and here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli works based on the concept of image recognition. Sikuli compares the input image with the complete UI displayed on the screen and performs the actions (ex: clicking on the UI based in the input image).
Sikuli can be integrated with the Java+Webdriver automation to perform the task's which are not supported by webdriver.

For steps refer below:-
https://automation-home.blogspot.in/2014/08/Sikuli-Installation.html

Above steps give you sikuli-java.jar which you can use in your java project

refer below:-

[How to get sikuli-script.jar for Windows 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114511/how-to-get-sikuli-script-jar-for-windows-64-bit-machine)

After following above steps at the time of 1st run you can get the error related to JavaSoft. To over come from that  issue use below steps:-

Go into your Start Menu and type regedit into the search field.
Navigate to the following path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft
Right click on the JavaSoft folder and click on New -> Key
Name the new Key Prefs and everything should work.

Some java code examples:-

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-1/

Hope it will help you :)